# SQL Subquery in WHERE clauses resulting in error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to use these conditions in my SELECT statement and they work up until my subquery where I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

I've tried 3 different ways, table variable, temp table, my original table value function and all have failed.

```
AND (@LOBCODE IS NULL OR (HP.LOBCODE = @LOBCODE))
AND (@POS IS NULL OR (CM.PLACESVC = @POS))
AND (@Modif1 IS NULL OR (CD.MODIF = @Modif1))

AND (@procCode IS NULL OR (CD.PROCCODE IN (SELECT proccode FROM #procCodes))
AND (@procCode IS NULL OR (CD.PROCCODE IN (SELECT proccode FROM @procCodeTable))
AND (@ProcCode IS NULL OR (CD.PROCCODE IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitStrings_XML (@ProcCode, ',')))
```

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Show the error.

Comment: (3) Count your open and close parens on the last line...

Comment: Please show COMPLETE (not a part of it) sql query, and first count the parens...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second block of statements, each is missing a terminating parenthesis `)`. Count the number of left  parentheses, and then count the number of right parentheses.